# Reboot on hardware freeze

Tags: freeze, ubuntu-12.04, hardware-failure

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 12.04

How can I make sure that even if the kernel has a very low level, massive failure, the system will reboot? Or if that is impossible, what is the best freeze to reboot coverage that can be achieved?

Is there anyway that I can leverage hardware based timers or interrupts to force a reboot?

I would prefer solutions that work on generic and inexpensive hardware.

Bonus Question: Would you recommend this as a stock/default solution?

### Further illustration:

Lets say I am experiencing what seems to be very low level freezes. (Not even the magic SysRq Keys work)

I can't ssh into the machine either, however it does seem like the tcp handshake was successful. (wierd? Has to an instrumentation failure, right?)

This could possibly be due to bad memory or overheating but lets say for the moment that I am not very concerned with the immediate cause, and instead I am more concerned with maximizing the short term uptime.  (Even though I fully acknowledge that understanding the cause is the best way to prevent it from happening in the long term)

### Research:

I am currently looking into this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reboot-linux-box-after-a-kernel-panic.html however I am not convinced that I am actually getting to a panic as there are no visual indicators.

This seems to be what I want: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/watchdog.8.html However it seems to rely on a `/dev/watchdog` which my system doesn't seem to have.  Am I missing something?

If I follow the checks here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaai.crashdump%2Fliaaicrashdumpnmiwatch.htm it seems that NMI is working on my system, however it didn't reboot the system on a failure.  What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're machine doesn't come along with a hardware watchdog, there are still several software based kernel mechanisms, that could work for you.  First of all, there's a software watchdog implementation called `softdog`, which can be used with `watchdog` like a real hardware watchdog.  You can test whether your kernel supports a software watchdog by testing whether `modprobe softdog` loads the kernel module.  This would also give you `/dev/watchdog`.  If your kernel doesn't provide support for `softdog` you would have to build your own kernel and enable `CONFIG_SOFT_WATCHDOG`:

```
config SOFT_WATCHDOG
     tristate "Software watchdog"
     select WATCHDOG_CORE
     help
       A software monitoring watchdog. This will fail to reboot your system
       from some situations that the hardware watchdog will recover
       from. Equally it's a lot cheaper to install.

       To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
       module will be called softdog.
```

One other mechanism provided by the kernel is the *Hangcheck Timer*, enabled by the option `CONFIG_HANGCHECK_TIMER`:

```
config HANGCHECK_TIMER
     tristate "Hangcheck timer"
     depends on X86 || IA64 || PPC64 || S390
     help
       The hangcheck-timer module detects when the system has gone
       out to lunch past a certain margin.  It can reboot the system
       or merely print a warning.
```

Also (at least on x86) there's the *NMI Lockup Detector* as a third mechanism to automatically reboot your system on hangs:

```
config LOCKUP_DETECTOR
     bool "Detect Hard and Soft Lockups"
     depends on DEBUG_KERNEL && !S390
     help
       Say Y here to enable the kernel to act as a watchdog to detect
       hard and soft lockups.

       Softlockups are bugs that cause the kernel to loop in kernel
       mode for more than 20 seconds, without giving other tasks a
       chance to run.  The current stack trace is displayed upon
       detection and the system will stay locked up.

       Hardlockups are bugs that cause the CPU to loop in kernel mode
       for more than 10 seconds, without letting other interrupts have a
       chance to run.  The current stack trace is displayed upon detection
       and the system will stay locked up.

       The overhead should be minimal.  A periodic hrtimer runs to
       generate interrupts and kick the watchdog task every 4 seconds.
       An NMI is generated every 10 seconds or so to check for hardlockups.

       The frequency of hrtimer and NMI events and the soft and hard lockup
       thresholds can be controlled through the sysctl watchdog_thresh.

config HARDLOCKUP_DETECTOR
     def_bool y
     depends on LOCKUP_DETECTOR && !HAVE_NMI_WATCHDOG
     depends on PERF_EVENTS && HAVE_PERF_EVENTS_NMI
```

Don't be frightened by the dependency on `DEBUG_KERNEL`, since this is enable on most distribution kernels anyways.

**Note:** Since all of this are software mechanisms, there's no guarantee that they will detect *all* lockups.  As the help text for `SOFT_WATCHDOG` already mentions, there are situations all of those won't recover from.  But rebooting on *many* situations is at least better than hanging in *all* of them. ;)